# Acess to pip Activity From Another Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, picture-in-picture

How Can i access to methods and finish my picture in picture activity from MainActivity

for example i want to pause videoplayer on pip mode from MainActivity:

```
VideoPlayerActivity().pauseVideo()
```

VideoPlayerActivity (Pip):

```
    fun pauseVideo() {
        player?.pause()
    }
```

but it not working

I expected the video to stop but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

When you try to call `VideoPlayerActivity().pauseVideo()`, you are creating a new `VideoPlayerActivity` class and it will call that new class `pauseVideo()` instead of the original displaying class `pauseVideo()`.

One suggestion can be creating a separate Singleton class, so that you can access your `Player` functions from any `Activity`.

```kotlin
class PlayerHelper {
    companion object {
        private var instance : PlayerHelper? = null
        // Define your necessary Player tool

        fun getInstance(): PlayerHelper {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = PlayerHelper()
            }

            return instance!!
        }
    }

    fun start() {
        // Implement to start your player
        Log.i("PlayerHelper", "start:")
    }

    fun pause() {
        // Implement to pause your player
        Log.i("PlayerHelper", "pause:")
    }
}
```

And you can call `pause()` in any Activity like:

```kotlin
PlayerHelper.getInstance().pause()
```